# Linking one cell to another in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a dynamically generated spreadsheet.  I would like to be able to allow the viewer to go to a different sheet/cell when a cell is clicked on. I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to do this.

Going to the new cell is fairly easy: `Spreadhseet.setActiveSheet()/Spreadsheet.setActiveRange()` work fine.  My thought was to encode the link destination in the contents of the source cell, and then write a script to "follow" the link.

I tried using images or drawings.  But there were two problems with this: while images can be inserted programmatically, I did not see a way to programmatically associate a script with them.  And the called script does not have an associated event tied to it, so there is no way to see what cell the user clicked (clicking an image does not set the active cell).

I thought about using `onEdit()`.  This almost works, but `onEdit` is only triggered on changes (not selection) so the user actually has to modify the cell in order to "link".  When testing I tended to zap the contents of the cell by accident with `onEdit`.

I tried making a menu item, and in the menu's script get the active cell's contents to determine where to go to.  This worked but was a bit more difficult for the user than I was hoping for.

I was hoping someone would have a creative solution to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing the drawing or image insertion should work since it has exactly the same functionality as the menu item.  You can assign a script to it just like in a menu.

Comment: But you can only add a script to an image from the UI; there is no api for adding a script to an image (unlike a menu, which does have an api)